# Write trigger function to update only one row

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I have 2 tables: `table_1` and `table_2`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.table_1
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table_1_id_seq'::regclass),
    dt time without time zone,
    value numeric,
    CONSTRAINT table_1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.table_2
(
    table_1_id integer,
    dt timestamp without time zone,
    table_1_flag integer
)
```

`table_1` is constantly updating with new records and has autoincrement on id column.

`table_2` contains only one row. This row contain last `id` and `dt` from `table_1`.

What do I need:

Whenever new `id` appears in `table_1`, that one row in `table_2` should be updated with new `id` and `dt` from `table_1` and set `table_1_flag` to 1.

Comment: That is simple with a row-level trigger; just read the documentation. The question is: what are you trying to achieve with that, except potentially crippling performance?

Comment: This is temporary solution, later this table will be deleted.